# get first 1000 results from a google search

Tags: c#, get, hyperlink, google-search

I'm trying to get the first 1000 search result links in google with C#. So far, I've modified Shiv Kumar's [Finding links on a Web page](http://www.matlus.com/finding-links-on-a-web-page) 
to look for links in: 
string webpageUrl = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&num=100&q=" + "concept";
however since the google page doesn't show all the 1000 results i need to find the way to get the rest of them. 
could that be accomplished without google api?

gilibi

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657548/is-it-ok-to-scrape-data-from-google-results/22703153#22703153
What you are looking for is called "scraping" in IT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend you use the API.

Using "screen scraping" from HTML is problematic and requires frequent maintenance work - especially on a page like Google which will almost certainly change several times a year and which often uses redirects to track link usage.

---

Alternatively, if you really want to use the HTML route then take a look at the query parameters - e.g. "&start=10" - this should allow you to iterate over the pages.

But there's no guarantee that the query parameters will remain constant forever.

Comment: Definitely use the API if possible.  Otherwise, write code that does individual queries with: "&start=100&num=100", "&start=200&num=100", etc. Be aware, though, that Google frowns on screen scraping and will throttle you if you do it too much. I would recommend a delay of at least 15 seconds between requests.