# how to access the first result of a google search result ( prominently a video link)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, youtube-api, google-search

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=black+sabbath+%E2%80%93+iron+man&oq=black+sabbath+%E2%80%93+iron+man&aqs=chrome..69i57.461j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

In the link provided above, the very first result is the video link to the youtube, I want to access the link provided. How can I do that in python?

EDIT: My input will be a string that I query in the google-search box. Like in this case "black sabbath iron man"

Comment: What have you tried? Also, be more specific: do you want just to have that link as a string? Do you want to retrieve the contents from that link?

Comment: You could probably use BeautifulSoup for this.

Comment: yes i want to consider the exact link as a string! @Oliver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scraping HTML is *fragile* -- yes you can do it with beautifulsoup4, e.g

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_string)
href = soup.find('h3').find('a').get('href')
print(href)
```

will show **/url?q=http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D9LjbMVXj0F8&sa=U&ei=ESCPVPD6NcT3yQS-04C4DA&ved=0CBQQtwIwAA&usg=AFQjCNGV1u7FshGW4K_Ffu0zLzwaW7sCzw** or the like.  However, the slightest cosmetic change to Youtube search results might break your application.

Better to register your app with Google and use the provided API, as per [Google's own docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).  The Python client library nicely supports App Engine, see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python_appengine for example.

Comment: BeautifulSoup's CSS support makes this a little more readable and robust with `soup.select('h3 a[href]')[0]['href']`. Not sure if the user was after just YouTube videos or Google search results though, there is no good API for the latter, right? (And welcome back to answering! :-))

Comment: Hi Martijn, yes you can scrape a little more robustly, but it will still be very fragile. You're right that the Google Search API was turned off recently after 3+ years of deprecation -- and scraping search results violates the TOS, as mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657548/is-it-ok-to-scrape-data-from-google-results .