# google search by google api in r or python

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, google-api, google-api-python-client

I want to search some thing (ex:"python language") in google by python or R and it will give me the list of links for that google search
like:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)
https://www.python.org/
https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/
```

Is there any api for that 
I went through this question 
[How to get google search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889136/how-to-get-google-search-results)

but problem is sometime it is working and most of the time it is not working and giving only empty list() as an output.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi*.

You can use the [`google-search-results`](https://pypi.org/project/google-search-results) package to extract links from Google Search.

[Full example at Repl.it](https://repl.it/@serpapi/GoogleSearchApi)

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "coffee",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY")
}

client = GoogleSearch(params)
data = client.get_dict()

print("Organic results\n")

for result in data['organic_results']:
  print(f"Link: {result['link']}")
```

Response

```json
{
    "organic_results": [
    {
      "position": 1,
      "title": "Coffee - Wikipedia",
      "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee",
      "displayed_link": "en.wikipedia.org › wiki › Coffee",
      "thumbnail": null,
      "snippet": "Coffee is a brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, the seeds of berries from certain Coffea species.",
      "sitelinks": {
        "inline": [
          {
            "title": "History of coffee",
            "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_coffee"
          },
          {
            "title": "Coffee bean",
            "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_bean"
          },
          {
            "title": "Coffee production",
            "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_production"
          },
          {
            "title": "Coffee preparation",
            "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_preparation"
          }
        ],
        "list": [
          {
            "date": "Color‎: ‎Black, dark brown, light brown, beige"
          }
        ]
      },
      "rich_snippet": {
        "bottom": {
          "detected_extensions": {
            "introduced‎_‎th_century": 15
          },
          "extensions": [
            "Introduced‎: ‎15th century",
            "Color‎: ‎Black, dark brown, light brown, beige"
          ]
        }
      },
      "cached_page_link": "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:U6oJMnF-eeUJ:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us",
      "related_pages_link": "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&q=related:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee+Coffee&tbo=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl7er0gLvoAhWRQN4KHRqmAQwQHzADegQIAhAH"
    },
    {
      "position": 2,
      "title": "The House of Coffi - Coffee Shop - Dover, Delaware - 132 ...",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/TheHouseOfCoffi/",
      "displayed_link": "www.facebook.com › Places › Dover, Delaware › Restaurant",
      "thumbnail": null,
      "snippet": "People talk about \"iced mocha coffee\", \"flavored iced tea\" and \"chai tea\". Relaxing atmosphere・Expert baristas・Convenient location. My first visit was a very ...",
      "rich_snippet": {
        "top": {
          "detected_extensions": {
            "rating": 5,
            "votes": 132
          },
          "extensions": [
            "Rating: 5",
            "132 votes"
          ]
        }
      }
    }

    // Stripped...
  ]
}
```

**Output**

```
Organic results

Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee
Link: https://www.amazon.com/coffee/s?k=coffee
Link: https://www.kansas.com/entertainment/restaurants/dining-with-denise-neil/article4383840.html
Link: https://www.reverieroasters.com/
Link: https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/270202
Link: http://www.ncausa.org/about-coffee/what-is-coffee
Link: http://www.ncausa.org/about-coffee
Link: https://www.facebook.com/KookaburraCoffeeLyfe/
```

If you want more information, check out [SerpApi documentation](https://serpapi.com/organic-results).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this [python web search api](https://github.com/rohithpr/py-web-search) to perform google search in python. Fairly straightforward to use and easy to install.