# How to scrape description under Google search link?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have looked for  answers here : [How to scrape description of first link from Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858773/how-to-scrape-description-of-first-link-from-google) but the solution seems to be outdated for some reason. So i am stuck with the code in the previous question.
(Thanks in advance for yor answers)