# Keyword Extraction & Computation from multiple URLs

Tags: r, tf-idf, text-extraction

I have a project to extract keywords from URLs generated from a Search Query using R. Then, identify the most frequent keywords, compute for the TF-IDF, etc. of these extracted keywords.

Being new to R, I have tried the following approach. I used two different links then I:

**STEP 1**: I did keyword extraction using this code: [Web Scraping and Text Mining in R](https://quantmacro.wordpress.com/2016/04/30/web-scraping-for-text-mining-in-r/). I ran this code twice because I am extracting 2 URLs by changing the links in the getURL() in the code. *RESULT: I have **1 dtm for each URL** **extracted**.*

**STEP 2**: To compute for the tf-idf, I analyzed and used Chapter 3 in this document: http://tidytextmining.com/tfidf.html. I patterned my data based on the document by:

1. Converting each dtm into a dataframe
2. Add new columns "Sitename/URL" and "Total no. of Terms" to the dataframes
3. Append dataframe of link2 to link1 as they have the same columns
4. Then I used the formula in the document to compute for the 'term frequency' and the function **bind_tf_idf** for the computation of tf-idf

The objective is to extract keywords from the URLs generated from a Search Query. I have already generated URLs by using the following code: [How to get google search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889136/how-to-get-google-search-results). ***(see below for the snippet of code)***

Once extracted, identify the number of occurrence of these keywords, the most frequent keywords used, then compute for the TF-IDF of these keywords.

As a beginner, this is the best I could come up with (i did really try though), but I definitely think that there's a better approach in doing this rather than doing Step 1 and Step 2 for every URLs.

Your help and/or feedback on this is greatly appreciated.

```
> search.term <- "tour package"
> quotes <- "FALSE"
> search.url <- getGoogleURL(search.term=search.term, quotes=quotes)
> links <- getGoogleLinks(search.url)
> links <- gsub('/url\\?q=','',sapply(strsplit(links[as.vector(grep('url',links))],split='&'),'[',1)) 
> links
 [1] "https://www.makemytrip.com/holidays-india/"                 
 [2] "https://www.makemytrip.com/holidays-india/"                 
 [3] "https://www.yatra.com/india-tour-packages"                   
 [4] "http://www.thomascook.in/tcportal/international-holidays"   
 [5] "https://www.yatra.com/holidays"                             
 [6] "https://www.travelguru.com/holiday-packages/domestic-packages.shtml"
 [7] "https://www.chanbrothers.com/package"                       
 [8] "https://www.tourmyindia.com/packagetours.html"               
 [9] "http://traveltriangle.com/tour-packages"                     
[10] "http://www.coxandkings.com/bharatdeko/"                     
[11] "https://www.sotc.in/india-tour-packages"
```