# Google Search in R

Tags: r, google-api

I have a list of keywords in an excel file which I would like to search about in Google through R.
The output should contain the following :
Position (I want the first 10 outputs with the position)
Name of the Article
Text (the preview as shown in Google)
URL
Domain

I'm new to R please help. Also, please suggest if there is a package available that helps shorten the process.

Comment: See [Is it ok to scrape data from Google results?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22703153/13473361) or  [How to get google search results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32889136/13473361)