# Is it appropriate to use Google Custom Search Engine for seeding a crawler?

Tags: web-crawler, google-custom-search, seeding

I can use the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) to make a query and receive results in JSON format. However, what bothers me is in the [Terms and Conditions](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1714300) (in 1.4 Appropriate Conduct):

*(l) "crawl", "spider", index or in any non-transitory manner store or cache information obtained from the Service (including, but not limited to, Results, or any part, copy or derivative thereof)*

According to my understanding, I cannot use the results as seeds to my web crawler. So I have following questions:

1. Am I right?
2. If I am right, is there any option from Google allows that?
3. Can I use equivalent APIs from Yahoo and Bing for this purpose?

Comment: It seems [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657548/is-it-ok-to-scrape-data-from-google-results?lq=1) help to answer my question: _I know of no lawsuit from Google against a scraper. Even Microsoft scraped Google, they powered their search engine Bing with it_