# What does return['string'] do?

Tags: python, return

The below block of code below is taken from the following forum [Programmatically searching google in Python using custom search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083058/programmatically-searching-google-in-python-using-custom-search)

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pprint

my_api_key = "Google API key"
my_cse_id = "Custom Search Engine ID"

def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']

results = google_search(
    'stackoverflow site:en.wikipedia.org', my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=10)
for result in results:
    pprint.pprint(result)
```

In the function `google_search` I am having trouble understanding why and what happens when `res` is returned as `res['items']` verses just `res`.

EDIT: Perhaps showing the result of changing of the two variants would help.

When `res['items']` is used `results` is a dictionary of containing 10 values each containing 11 items.

When just `res` is used `results` is a  dictionary containing 6 items each each containing a different number of items and data structures.

Comment: Looks like a key-value type arrangement. Get the value of the entry with the key 'string'. Pretty straight forward.

Comment: Hint: `return` has very little to do with this. `res['items']` is just another expression that produces a result.

Comment: You may want to read the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries); I linked you directly to the section that uses that very syntax; you may want to [start at the beginning](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is returning the value of that key in the variable `res`.

Imagine a data structure like the following:

```
{
    "errors": [],
    "items": [ "item1", "item2", "item3"],
    "status": "success"
}
```

This is a regular python dictionary that you could use in your project right now. If `res` was a reference to that dictionary then the following would be true:

```
res['items'] == [ "item1", "item2", "item3"]
```

In other words, it would return the array indicated by that index in the dictionary. It is essentially equivalent of `res[0]` for named indices.

Comment: I don't work with dictionaries much but that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that res is a dictionary object. Returning `res['items']` will return the values stored with the key `'items'` in the dictionary object `res`.

Answer (score 0):

`res` is a disctionnary, here is an example of what it could contain :

```
res = {
    'item_count': 50, 
    'items': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
    'search' : 'search terms here'
}
```

If you return `res`, then you get everything in the results. In my example you could access `item_count` for instance and get the number of results.

Returning `res['items']` you get only the list of items resulting your query.