# When parsing google cse html in a text file, TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, regex

I apologize if something like this has been asked, but I'm a beginner in Python and can't figure this out. I recently created a Google CSE to look over linkedin and return structured data using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083058/programmatically-searching-google-in-python-using-custom-search). The API works fine, but now I'm trying to put the code on a text document to parse on my computer. Whenever try to run it with my regular expression, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My_PC\Desktop\CSE.py", line 41, in <module>
    snippet = re.search(snip,cse).group(1)
  File "C:\Users\My_PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

So I tried putting b in front of my regex to convert it to bytes. That led to the same error, so I tried encoding it in utf-8 in the regex, which lead to the same error.

Once again, I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I just can't figure out. Could someone please tell me what I am getting wrong?

Here is my code, if it helps:

```
def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch","v1",developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']


    a=0
    with open('list.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            name = row[1]+' '+row[2]+' '+row[4]
            print("This trial will search for", name)
            print()
            results = google_search(name, my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=1)
            #for result in results:
            #    pprint.pprint(result)
            a += 1
            print()
            print("This is trial", a)
            print()
            print('+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+')
            print()
            time.sleep(2)
            with open("cse_results.txt", "w+", encoding='utf-8') as cse:#make the files cse_results.txt. cse_results.txt is truncated if it exists
                cse.write(str(results))#write results to cse_results.txt 
                snip = b'View\s<b>(.+?)&nb'#find string that starts with View in html
                snippet = re.search(snip,cse).group(1)
                print(snippet)#check if regex was captured
            with open("cse_parse.txt", "a") as par:#append the found snippet to the cse_parse.txt file
                par.write(snippet)
            for line in cse:
                snippet = re.findall(snip,line)#search cse_results.txt for the snip pattern
                print(snippet)#print it to ensure that the regex was found
                par.write("HTML Snippet:"+snippet)#append match text to to cse_parse.txt
            if a >= 0:
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.search()` is expecting a string or bytes-like object, as it states. You are giving it `cse`, which is a file object in your code.

Comment: I juust changed the cse variable to lookUp in my own code, as well as fixed indentations to properly reflect code that code block. I'm still having the same error. Is it because I'm working within an open csv file (list.csv), even though I'm trying to run the regex on a txt file (cse_results.txt)?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I had to convert snip and result in re.search() into strings.

To clarify, I was under the impression that the regex in snip was already in string format, and I did not think of result being an issue since it was what I was searching. I was actually under the impression that they both had to be in bytes, since the information was being grabbed of the internet.

I went back to cut down on the code, but here is what I have for reference:

```
with open('list.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        name = row[1] + ' ' + row[2] + ' ' +row[4]
        print("This trial will search for", name)
        results = google_search(name, my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=1)
        for result in results:
            print(result)
            snip = r'View\s<b>(.+?)&nb'
            snippet = re.search(str(snip),str(result)).group(1)
            with open("cse_result.txt", "w+") as nameLookup:
                nameLookup.write(snippet)
            print()
```