# Googlesearch with python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to run below script:

```
import urllib
import json as m_json
query = raw_input ( 'Query: ' )
query = urllib.urlencode ( { 'q' : query } )
response = urllib.urlopen ( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&' + query ).read()
json = m_json.loads ( response )
results = json [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]
for result in results:
    title = result['title']
    url = result['url']   # was URL in the original and that threw a name error exception
    print ( title + '; ' + url )
```

My output is:

```
Query: test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    results = json [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API

Comment: `json['responseData']` is `None`. See [here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print the result and you will see the following:

*The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)*

Try that ;) good luck

PS: For more info, you may like to visit [this detailed tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083058/programmatically-searching-google-in-python-using-custom-search) in another stack overflow question

Answer (score 2):

After printing out the raw json with the following code:

```
print(str(json))
```

we get the following response from google:

```
{'responseData': None, 'responseDetails': 'The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)', 'responseStatus': 403}
```

A solution can be found here:

[What are the alternatives now that the Google web search API has been deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated)