# How to find similar pages in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 10 web pages in google sheets. I load them all into a Python list and now I want to find similar web pages on the internet (let's say another 10). In Chrome, there is an addon called "Google similar pages". Is there any simple way of using this with Python or any other solution? Thanks for any help in advance!

EDIT I do not want to build an algorithm that creates a list o "similar pages" on the internet but use some ready-to-go solution. My first thought was to use "Google Similar Pages" addon and send a request to it from Python, but maybe there is another service with appropriate API?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by similar? I don't think this is the right place to ask this question. Please edit the details, if you have something more specific in mind.

Comment: Ok, done I edited it

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer. The easiest way to find similar pages for a list of links is to send a request to google with "related:www.exampleadress.com". The proper way of communicating with google is here: [Programmatically searching google in Python using custom search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083058/programmatically-searching-google-in-python-using-custom-search)

but apparently free accounts are limited to 100 queries per day...

anyway, it works for now :)