# Get "keyInvalid" when requesting Google Custom Search API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I am trying to automate search queries re [Programmatically searching google in Python using custom search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083058/programmatically-searching-google-in-python-using-custom-search/37084643#37084643) and and keep receiving this error for a simple search:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
import pprint
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = os.environ.get('API_KEY', None)
cse_id = os.environ.get('CSE_ID', None)


def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']


results = google_search(
    'coding', api_key, cse_id, num=3)
for result in results:
    pprint.pprint(result)
```

I doubled check the API key and have definitely not exceeded usage limits (only ran the program a couple times). I did restrict the API key to my IP address when I initially configured it (not sure if this is a potential cause; am new to API's and just want to test this one safely).

Answer (score 0):

Ahh.. figured it out. I stored the API key as an environmental variable with "" which somehow caused it to include quotes in the value, thus rendering it invalid. Works now!