# from googleapiclient.discovery import build ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'

Tags: visual-studio, pycharm, interpreter, pythoninterpreter

Visual Studio blows the below error:

> from googleapiclient.discovery import build ModuleNotFoundError: No
>   module named 'googleapiclient'

when I am running a script that reads google sheets using the:

> from googleapiclient.discovery import build from
>   google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

I have installed the libraries using `pip`

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib
```

the code runs fine in Pycharm but not when using other interpreter in VS.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try

```
pip install google-api-python-client
```

For more information,visit this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083058/programmatically-searching-google-in-python-using-custom-search)