# Google Sheets API with python. Refuses to find most modules, even though they exist

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've tried literally everything I could possibly find on the internet. The current error I get is
"No module named 'google_auth_oauthlib'" but when I look for the module, it says it exists.
I've also tried running the quickstart.py thing Google asks you to run and I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'"
Again, I've looked for it and it does exist. The code i'm trying to run is

```
import os
from Google import Create_Service
 
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = ('client_secret.json')
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'sheets'
API_VERSION = 'v4'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
 
service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
```

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: Should be Python 3.8

Comment: Make sure that you have the pip package management tool and see if downgrading to Python 3.6 solves the issue. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873824/from-googleapiclient-discovery-import-build-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58989483/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-googleapiclient).

Comment: Only the Python package.

Comment: Ill try that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Faced same issue. What I did:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib oauth2client
```

Then:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

file_id = "file_id"
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("json-file.json", scope)

drive_service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
```

That did the trick.