# How can I retrieve factual search results on Google using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve the first, most prominent factual search result on Google using Python. I am referring to something like this:

[image: search result example]

As you can see, the first search result is not a website or a video, but a simple response of very little words. The searches I would like to do using Python will be of a very similar nature, with such direct results being the most common first result.

Comment: I am almost sure that this would be against ToS of google ... But if you still consider it, have a look at `phantomjs` which I think you can use to get the page. The analysis in python can later be done with `BeautifulSoup` or similar package. The alternative to all this would be to look for a Google API to perform the queries

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084643/1207193?

Comment: @urban or use `python requests` or `selenium python`. But cool didn't know about `phantomjs`