# how to just retrieve the titles from the query result using rvest

Tags: html, r, rvest

I use rvest to retrieve the titles from google query result. My code is like this:

```
> url = URLencode(paste0("https://www.google.com.au/search?q=","600d"))
> page <- read_html(url)
> page %>% 
     html_nodes("a") %>%
     html_text()
```

However, the result includes not only just titles, but also something else, like:

```
 [24] "Past month"                                                                        
 [25] "Past year"                                                                         
 [26] "Verbatim"                                                                              
 [27] "EOS 600D - Canon"                                                                  
 [28] "Similar"                                                                           
 [29] "Canon 600D | BIG W"                                                                
 [30] "Cached"                                                                                
 [31] "Similar"   
 ......
 [45] ""                                                                                          
 [46] ""
```

where what I need are [27] "EOS 600D - Canon" and [29] "Canon 600D | BIG W". They are shown in google query like this:[image]

All of others are just noises for me. Could anyone please tell me how to get rid of those?

Also, if I want the description part as well, what I should do?

Comment: worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22703153/5977215

Comment: Scraping Google is a violation of their Terms of Service and you're also asking other do violate it with this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just get the titles, do not use `<a>` (=link) but `<h3>`:

```
page %>% 
  html_nodes("h3") %>%
  html_text()

 [1] "EOS 600D - Canon"                                                   
 [2] "Canon EOS 600D - Wikipedia"                                         
 [3] "Canon 600D | BIG W"                                                 
 [4] "Canon EOS 600D Digital SLR Camera with 18-55mm IS Lens Kit ..."     
 [5] "Canon Rebel T3i / EOS 600D Review: Digital Photography Review"      
 [6] "Canon EOS 600D review - CNET"                                       
 [7] "canon eos 600d | Cameras | Gumtree Australia Free Local Classifieds"
 [8] "Images for 600d"                                                    
 [9] "Canon 600D - Snapsort"                                              
[10] "Canon EOS 600D - Georges Cameras"
```

Comment: Wow! this is amazing ! Thanks a lot!