# How to get google rank without getting blocked or capcha?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, rank

This is what I do in my program:

- Use CURL to google search the keywords
- Filter the results and compare to my aritcle

But when it run to 84th article, I got capcha to input. The number of articles is about 2000.

How to get the google rank without getting blocked or capcha?

Any comment is appriciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you use CURL google will block you after a while, but they offer an API for doing what you want that shouldn't block you: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [Is it ok to scrape data from Google results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657548/is-it-ok-to-scrape-data-from-google-results/22703153#22703153)

You should always do everything you can to NOT get into a captcha, no matter what site you scrape.
Captcha/block means you have been detected and that causes issues.
The site owner does not like it for sure, causing administrative work etc.

Check the answer of mine I linked, also the linked sites there. You can learn a lot about how to scrape Google (and how not)