# When scraping a Google page, the 1st page is duplicated in output. What should I do?

Tags: r

Google searches for "Smart Factory" and scraping a large number of pages.
Google's source is starting (0-90) instead of the start page (1-10), but the first page does not read the contents of each page and duplicates the output.

My code:

```
library(rvest)
library(KoNLP)

title <- lapply(paste0('https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=smart+factory&ei=MNEnWZfgJoPw0AS7-aYY&sa=N&biw=1011&bih=677&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.#safe=active&q=smartfactory&start=', 0:90),
          function(url){

            url %>% read_html() %>% 
              html_nodes(".r") %>% 
              html_text()

          })

title
```

Also, when outputting in Korean, the language is broken and output.

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22703153/4132844

Comment: As a side-note, if you are going to be scraping a lot from Google search pages, I would add in a `Sys.sleep()` argument that gets a random number from a strange distribution of numbers. I've gotten booted from Google before due to making my scraping too obvious (and I really only did ~150 scrapes). EDIT: Ah, I see @scoa linked to a good discussion in this.