# Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, connection

I am making a web scraper but i am facing some errors.help is required.

My Code:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.google.com")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for x in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(x)
```

Error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016945AFB0F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

Comment: Does http://www.google.com allow web scrapers?

Comment: Not saying this will fix it. But try installing `pyopenssl`, I had this problem once. `pip install pyopenssl`

Comment: See [Is it ok to scrape data from Google results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657548/is-it-ok-to-scrape-data-from-google-results)

Comment: Or you are sending too many requests hence the _"Max retires exceeded with url"_. Try with a different URL to see if you still get the error. Those are the two most likely cases.

Comment: Eventually google will cut you off.