# How to get the keys from preg_match_all?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

The code was working:

```
$url  = 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbo=d&site=&source=hp&q=upoznavanje';
$html = file_get_html($url);
preg_match_all('/(?<="><cite>).*?(?=<\/cite><div\ class=)/', $html, $output);
    
foreach ($output[0] as $link) { 
  $link ."<br>"  ;
}
```

When I added `echo $output[0]`, now I get 0, and nothing in `$output[1]`.

`var_dump` works and `print_r` array is there, but how do I get unique values of each without foreach?

#### var_dump:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(21) "https://www.elmaz.rs/" [1]=> string(47) "https://badoo.com/sr/upoznavanje/serbia/" [2]=> string(39) "https://serbiandating.com/?locale=sr_RS" [3]=> string(30) "https://www.lepoticaizver.com/" [4]=> string(22) "www.prvi-sastanak.net/" [5]=> string(122) "https://www.telegraf.rs/.../1878507-top-5-aplikacija-za-muvanje-ovo-su- najbolji-sajtovi-za-upoznavanje-i-dejt-foto" [6]=> string(137) "https://www.telegraf.rs/.../1863749-dopisivala-sam-se-sa-muskarcinama-na- sajtu-za-upoznavanje-uh-kakve-sam-sve-ponude-dobila-foto" [7]=> string(24) "https://www.iskrica.com/"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression (Regex) for HTML parsing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585087/regular-expression-regex-for-html-parsing-in-php)

Comment: this will work for about 5 minutes because Google is really good at stopping people scraping their search results.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657548/is-it-ok-to-scrape-data-from-google-results

Comment: the scraper works fine allways , when i put it in foreach, i do not understand why not work with  $output[0]

Comment: `$link . "<br />";` is a pretty pointless line since it doesn't actually _do_ anything. Also, could you post the results of `var_dump($output);`

Comment: yes missing echo, i try to remove all not point code ,  but want to tell that foreach works,  there is var_dump:   array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(21) "https://www.elmaz.rs/" [1]=> string(47) "https://badoo.com/sr/upoznavanje/serbia/" [2]=> string(39) "https://serbiandating.com/?locale=sr_RS" [3]=> string(30) "https://www.lepoticaizver.com/" [4]=> string(22) "www.prvi-sastanak.net/" [5]=> string(122) "https://www.telegraf.rs/.../1878507-top-5-aplikacija-za-muvanje-ovo-su- najbolji-sajtovi-za-upoznavanje-i-dejt-foto"

Comment: I short list because limitation

Comment: Please don't post large chunks of code in comments. It's unreadable. Edit your question to include all the information instead.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,added in post, but still the code not full, i get warning - can not post more then 8 links

Comment: I try now and with some simple  input text, not work too, it means preg_match_all i can take data only from loop, or i missing something ?

Comment: Which content do you want to search???

Comment: @A.ANoman you can see clearly on main post what is content, but i try and with simple text, on my side function preg_match_all not work when i try take data with key  $output[0] , only when put array in foreach

Comment: @ekvador I had faced same problem. But I search a content from a file not url. Like `IP_Address` search from a file. And it works fine for me

Comment: What work exatcly on your side,  we have function    preg_match_all( regex, input,output )   right, when i take $output[0]  , i not get first data in array, only when put array in foreach loop, do  you get  $output[0]  correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do that with extracting single data from array without loop:

```
print_r($output[0][0]);
```