# Downloading google images

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've found this library to download images from google using a keyword but i don´t understand how to use it. How it would be the code to download one image from a keyword and store it into a an specific folder?
thanks

https://google-images-download.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Just go to google, make a search, go to images, right click on the image you want to download and click `save image as`.. any other way is not liked by google. Even if you build something it will not work always, its gonna break sooner or later as google keeps on changing its code

Comment: The code uses selenium, which is an automation software. The following might examples might help: https://google-images-download.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#code-sample-importing-the-library.

Comment: my problem is that the example in a script doesn't download anything, and the others are for the console, not for a script

Comment: If you look at the code [here](https://github.com/hardikvasa/google-images-download/blob/master/google_images_download/google_images_download.py#L721), script is checking for class `rg_meta notranslate`, I guess that is no longer present

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google-Images-Search](https://pypi.org/project/Google-Images-Search/) to download images from google. But you'll need to use their API which costs money.

If you don't want to use the API for this you should read this:
[Is it ok to scrape data from Google results?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22703153/13872618)