# Is it possible to fetch data from google maps

Tags: google-maps, web-scraping

In the app I make, I need to know if a specific store is open, so i thought it would be a good idea to scrape the data from the Google Maps website, but i don't know if it is possible or legal, because you can do this with the Google places API, but it is too expansive.

I think I know the answer but I would like to her from you if anyone knows more about this, I tried to ask the Google support, but they didn't gave me a valid answer, so I am stuck with this question.

The part I want to use in my app is the sign: open, closed or opening soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much more difficult to scrape from google than from a lot of sites. Also if you read this previous stack overflow question that is basically the same as yours, google will limit you after a certain amount of requests.

[Is it ok to scrape data from Google results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657548/is-it-ok-to-scrape-data-from-google-results)